# how to index text file in solr line by line

Tags: solr, indexing

i have a large  Arabic Text File that contains Tweets each line contains one tweet ,
that i want to index in solr such that each line of this document should be indexed in a separate solr document

**what i tried so far :**

- i know how to SQL databse records in solr
- i know how to change solr
  schema to fit the data and working with Data import handler
- i know how the queries used to index data in solr

**what i want is :**

know how to index text file in solr in order that each line is considered a solr document

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking at the LineEntityProcessor of the DataImportHandler functionality. This is explained in detail in the below link.

LineEntityProcessor
This EntityProcessor reads all content from the data source on a line by line basis and returns a field called rawLine for each line read. The content is not parsed in any way; however, you may add transformers to manipulate the data within the rawLine field, or to create other additional fields.

http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler

Hope the information helps. Good luck!

Comment: would you please correct the link ? (link mentioned doesn't exist today (05-Jan-2018))